# Launching an admin application at boot-time?

Tags: windows-vista

I have a problem with a program that needs to be launched automatically at boot time.

To handle the FN keys (the "blue keys") on a [Samsung NP-R610-FS05FR](http://www.laptopsdirect.co.uk/Samsung_R610_Laptop_NP-R610-AS01UK/version.asp), it appears that we must launch a Samsung application called [Easy Display Manager](http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup//pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=45013&modelname=NP-P460I&modelcode&session_id=JCF0y128nthCLJhryczcgYXRsFDTDsHk82J1pg1CH6xR9251GC1m!-).

So I added an entry in HKLM...\Run.

But when rebooting, Vista blocked it, possibly because it requires admin rights.

Based on [this article](http://techpaul.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/manage-startup-programs-in-vista/), I used Windows Defender > Software Explorer, but the "Remove, Disable, Enable" buttons are greyed out, even when launching the app as admin.

I'm no Windows expert: If someone launches Easy Display Manager successfully, how did you do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Problems solved: After more research, it appears that I had to install EDM through a CD provided by Samsung called "System Software Media". After rebooting, EDM 2.2.10.1 is launched automatically and I can successfully use the Fn keys.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer & accept it?